# rdbuf and getline in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, cin, getline

I was looking at the cplusplus.com/reference/ to read more about rdbuf but I am still a bit confused. So I wanted to read std::cin twice, and heard that you can position your std::cin after reading the end of it. After a bit of research, this is what I came up with:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << cin.rdbuf();
while (getline(ss, line)) {
   cout << line << endl;
}
cin.seekg (0, cin.beg);
while (getline(cin, line)) {
   cout << line << endl;
}
```

It seems to be working fine, but I don't understand how and why this works.
For example why is it that this doesn't work?

```
while (getline(cin, line)) {
   cout << line << endl;
}
cin.seekg (0, cin.beg);
while (getline(cin, line)) {
   cout << line << endl;
}
```

[second version run in c++ shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpF3n.png)

Comment: Where is `line` defined? Also I'm not able to reproduce error if I add includes and define `line` as `std::string`. What do you mean by *doesn't work*, you are expecting something else, or you can't compile it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only posted the main meat of it. line is define above but not in the code shown here, its ```std::string```. By "doesn't work", I mean that I cannot read the ```std::cin``` twice. Compiling works just fine.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and it works as well as first version of your code.

Comment: The first version works, which I know. But the second version doesn't? I just ran it again in c++ shell, I will attach that ss to the question

Comment: Both versions worked [example](https://rextester.com/ISXE46595)

Comment: Your picture is only showing ```std::cin``` once, I want to read it twice. I don't think you understood my question correctly. Try just running the second version

Comment: My picture? Well go on link and run it (F8) there I copied both versions and provided 4 inputs. [Link](https://rextester.com/ISXE46595)

Comment: ...It's because you provided 4 inputs

Comment: If you want to write first input two times then both versions doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Yeah, its okay I appreciate your help. I think this only works if you pass in a file, which I do in my case. So wouldn't be testable on online editors.

Comment: Looks like you accidentally deleted most of the info from your question. I undid that for you. Please retry the intended edit, more carefully and without removing info.

Comment: What is `cin` connected to? Not all streams are seekable. You can't seek if `cin` is connected to a terminal or pipe.

Comment: But you can seek if it's connected to a file or stringstream.

Comment: The C++ streams are based on stream buffers, and finally some backends. If the stream is backed by a pipe, then you can only re-read what's in the buffer, but you can't re-read what has been read from the pipe.

Comment: `seekg` can fail, setting `failbit` on the stream. You might want to check that, otherwise `getline` will fail directly.

Comment: Would ```seekg``` fail if I read standard input from a file? For example, ```./myprogram < file.txt```So far, it's been working fine.